# Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method - FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I've this code wishing to fetch google mybusiness revies :

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/google-api/account-service-mybusiness.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage");

$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

$user_to_impersonate = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate); 

$client->authorize();

$locationName = "accounts/xxxxxxxxxx/locations/xxxxxxxxxx";

$myBusinessService = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);

$reviews = $myBusinessService->accounts_locations_reviews;
```

but when I try to fecth reviews I have this FATAL ERROR :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error":
>   "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to
>   retrieve access tokens using this method." } in
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176):
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #3
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(798):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Guzzl in
>   /web/htdocs/www.locandadalmoccia.it/home/google-api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 118

Can somneone help me to solve please?